# Please rename all [oculus-quest-%] tags to [meta-quest-%]? The name Oculus has disappeared, right?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

Please rename all [oculus-quest-#](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oculus-quest-%23) tags to [meta-quest-#](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-quest-%23)? The name Oculus has disappeared, right?

It should be clear to users that Meta (formerly Facebook) is behind this platform. Some will decide against a product from Meta/Zuckerberg for moral and ethical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renamed [oculus-quest-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oculus-quest-2) to [meta-quest-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-quest-2) and made the former tag a synonym.  Also updated tag excerpt and wiki.

Note this is/was the only "oculus-quest-#" tag on the site.